# how to assign selected value to RecurringDaysPicker for WP7

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7

I am using RecurringDaysPicker from toolkit for WP to select the day of the week for an application.

I have no issue to obtain the selection from the user, but I do have issue assigning back the user selection back to the RecurringDaysPicker when user want to edit/view their previous selection.

anybody can help?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should probably set your binding Mode to Mode=TwoWay

Comment: There is no "Mode=TwoWay" in RecurringDaysPicker.